# DPDK application test-pipeline fails in app_ports_check_link

Tags: linux, nic

Test Setup: `Linux-Server-1 Port-A <==> Port 1 DPDK-Server-2 Port 2 <==> Port B Linux-Server-2`.

Steps Followed:

1. The physical links are connected
2. Devices bound to DPDK:

```
Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:03:00.0 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=ixgbe,vfio-pci
0000:03:00.1 '82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection 10fb' drv=uio_pci_generic unused=ixgbe,vfio-pci

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:05:00.0 'I210 Gigabit Network Connection 1533' if=enp5s0 drv=igb unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic *Active*
0000:06:00.0 'I210 Gigabit Network Connection 1533' if=enp6s0 drv=igb unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic
```

Issue: **Port 2 of DPDK-Server is returning down `app_ports_check_link`**

[EDIT] Running with DPDK example, I am able to get packets send to DPDK port 1 and port 2.

Log for eventdev:

```
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:05:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1533 net_e1000_igb
EAL: PCI device 0000:06:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1533 net_e1000_igb
USER1: Creating the mbuf pool ...
USER1: Initializing NIC port 0 ...
USER1: Initializing NIC port 1 ...
USER1: Port 0 (10 Gbps) UP
USER1: Port 1 (0 Gbps) DOWN
PANIC in app_ports_check_link():
Some NIC ports are DOWN
8: [./build/pipeline(_start+0x2a) [0x558dc37c1d8a]]
7: [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f318e9f5b97]]
6: [./build/pipeline(main+0x7a) [0x558dc37c1fa4]]
5: [./build/pipeline(_Z8app_initv+0x18) [0x558dc37c2940]]
4: [./build/pipeline(+0x8c909) [0x558dc37c2909]]
3: [./build/pipeline(+0x8c677) [0x558dc37c2677]]
2: [./build/pipeline(__rte_panic+0xc5) [0x558dc37b4a90]]
1: [./build/pipeline(rte_dump_stack+0x2e) [0x558dc385954e]]
fish: “sudo ./build/pipeline” terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

**Code**

```
static void
app_ports_check_link(void)
{
    uint32_t all_ports_up, i;

    all_ports_up = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < app.n_ports; i++) {
        struct rte_eth_link link;
        uint16_t port;

        port = app.ports[i];
        memset(&link, 0, sizeof(link));
        rte_eth_link_get_nowait(port, &link);

        RTE_LOG(INFO, USER1, "Port %u (%u Gbps) %s\n",
            port,
            link.link_speed / 1000,
            link.link_status ? "UP" : "DOWN");

        if (link.link_status == ETH_LINK_DOWN)
            all_ports_up = 0;
    }

    if (all_ports_up == 0)
        rte_panic("Some NIC ports are DOWN\n");
}

static void
app_init_ports(void)
{
    uint32_t i;
    struct rte_eth_conf port_conf = app_port_conf_init();
    struct rte_eth_rxconf rx_conf = app_rx_conf_init();
    struct rte_eth_txconf tx_conf = app_tx_conf_init();
    (void)tx_conf;

    /* Init NIC ports, then start the ports */
    for (i = 0; i < app.n_ports; i++) {

        uint16_t port;
        int ret;

        port = app.ports[i];
        RTE_LOG(INFO, USER1, "Initializing NIC port %u ...\n", port);

        /* Init port */
        ret = rte_eth_dev_configure(
            port,
            1,
            1,
            &port_conf);
        if (ret < 0)
            rte_panic("Cannot init NIC port %u (%s)\n",
                    port, rte_strerror(ret));

        rte_eth_promiscuous_enable(port);

        /* Init RX queues */
        ret = rte_eth_rx_queue_setup(
            port,
            0,
            app.port_rx_ring_size,
            rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port),
            &rx_conf,
            app.pool);
        if (ret < 0)
            rte_panic("Cannot init RX for port %u (%d)\n",
                (uint32_t) port, ret);

        /* Init TX queues */
        ret = rte_eth_tx_queue_setup(
            port,
            0,
            app.port_tx_ring_size,
            rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port),
            NULL);
        if (ret < 0)
            rte_panic("Cannot init TX for port %u (%d)\n",
                (uint32_t) port, ret);

        /* Start port */
        ret = rte_eth_dev_start(port);
        if (ret < 0)
            rte_panic("Cannot start port %u (%d)\n", port, ret);
    }

    app_ports_check_link();
}
```

[EDIT] **2020/7/1 Update**

run `$RTE_SDK/examples/skeleton/build/basicfwd -l 1`, I got the following:

```
EAL: Detected 24 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:03:00.1 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:10fb net_ixgbe
EAL: PCI device 0000:05:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1533 net_e1000_igb
EAL: PCI device 0000:06:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1533 net_e1000_igb
Port 0 MAC: 9c 69 b4 60 90 26
Port 1 MAC: 9c 69 b4 60 90 27

Core 1 forwarding packets. [Ctrl+C to quit]
recv pkts num: 1, port: 0
================= Ether header ===============
srcmac: 9C:69:B4:60:90:17
dstmac: 33:33:00:00:00:16
ethertype: 34525
This packet is IPv6
================= Ether header ===============
srcmac: 9C:69:B4:60:90:17
dstmac: 33:33:00:00:00:16
ethertype: 34525
This packet is IPv6
send 1 pkts, port: 1
recv pkts num: 1, port: 1
================= Ether header ===============
srcmac: 9C:69:B4:60:90:1C
dstmac: 33:33:00:00:00:16
ethertype: 34525
This packet is IPv6
================= Ether header ===============
srcmac: 9C:69:B4:60:90:1C
dstmac: 33:33:00:00:00:16
ethertype: 34525
This packet is IPv6
send 1 pkts, port: 0
recv pkts num: 1, port: 1
================= Ether header ===============
srcmac: 9C:69:B4:60:90:1C
dstmac: 33:33:00:00:00:16
ethertype: 34525
This packet is IPv6
================= Ether header ===============
srcmac: 9C:69:B4:60:90:1C
dstmac: 33:33:00:00:00:16
ethertype: 34525
This packet is IPv6
send 1 pkts, port: 0
...
```

It seems that there is no problem with the two ports. Strange!

[EDIT] **2020/7/2 Update**

After **replacing `rte_eth_link_get_nowait` with `rte_eth_link_get`**, the program can work normally.

Following **@Vipin Varghese**'s suggestion, I have checked the ports' settings with `ethtool DEVNAME` and `ethtool -a DEVNAME`:

1. DPDK-server port-1:

```
Settings for ens1f1:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

2. others

```
Settings for ens1f0:
        Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
        Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full
                                10000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 10000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: FIBRE
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: d
        Wake-on: d
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

3. all ports have the same pause parameters

```
Autonegotiate:  off
RX:             on
TX:             on
```

But I'm really confused:

1. What's the difference between current settings and pause parameters? As you can see, in current settings, Auto-negotiation is on, but in pause parameters, Autonegotiate is off.
2. What's the difference between `rte_eth_link_get_nowait` and `rte_eth_link_get`? [DPDK doc](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html#a36ba70a5a6fce2c2c1f774828ba78f8d). Why `autoneg` can make them behave differently?

Comment: if you bind the ports `0000:03:00.0` and `0000:03:00.1` back to Linux driver are they making server3 ports up? if it is no, I request you check server3 ports states in dmesg. pleas update.

Comment: Update: the connection topology is ens1f0(server1) <-> ens1f1, ens1f0(server2) <-> ens1f1(server3). As my latest test, when NICs are all bound to Linux driver, four NICs can pass the test. After binding server2's NICs to DPDK, server1/3's NICs can pass the test, but the program still report "port1 down" error.

Comment: Are you running any DPDK application when testing with `ethtool -t` on server1 and servers. DPDK requires rte_eth_dev_start to be invoked to bring DPDK bound interface to be up. The ports will not be up by simply binding with DPDK driver. Quick test is to run `DPDK/examples/skeleton` by `$RTE_SDK/examples/skeleton/build/basicfwd -l 1 `. waiting for your updates

Comment: waiting for your update

Comment: Sorry to reply to you so late. I have updated the test result as your advice and the code.

Comment: When I test with `ethtool -t`, there is no DPDK application running on any servers.

Comment: it looks like `rte_eth_link_get` is API to be invoked, updated in answer. Waiting for reply to join `dpdk-debug` or `skype`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation:

1. Running `ethtool -while application is down is not a trusted way. Depending upon DPDK version` rte_eth_dev_close`or`rte_cleanup` would not have put the NIC in the right state.
2. But while running the application, if DPDK port-1 is coming as down following can be reason

a. Server-3 port might be auto-negotiating with DPDK port-1 leading to `rte_eth_link_get_nowait` to report as `down`. (right API is to invoke rte_eth_link_get).
b. The Server-3 port might manually be configured in non-duplex and non 10G mode.

the right way to debug is to

- put DPDK port back to the kernel as suggested in comments.
- cross-check auto-neg and speed.
- configure on server-1 and server-3 with `no auto-neg, 10G, full-duplex`
- bind the server-2 port-0 and port-1 to DPDK.
- run DPDK test-pipeline if possible with whitelist.
- run `ethtool -t` for port-B on server-3 to cross the results too.

note: this will help you identify if it server-3 ports driver/firmware which acts differently with auto-neg as the ports are sending and receiving packets is successful with `example/skeleton` with command `$RTE_SDK/examples/skeleton/build/basicfwd -l 1`

[EDIT-1] based on the update from the comment it looks like `rte_eth_link_get_nowait` is the fast approach, the right one is to be used with `rte_eth_link_get`. Requested for online debug with the author

[EDIT-2] based on the comment `rte_eth_link_get` has done the desired job. As I recollect `rte_eth_link_get` wait for the actual readout from physical device registers, while `rte_eth_link_get_nowait` is invoked without wait. hence the right values are populated for `rte_eth_link_get`.

Comment: But in my code, `app_init_ports` will call `rte_eth_dev_start` on ports, and there is no error message output, then it panic in `app_ports_check_link`.

Comment: please share your `app_ports_check_link` code as it is not a DPDK code as a separate since it is different

Comment: can you come in `https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215826/dpdk-debug` it looks like we are communicating 2 different things or skype? I assumed `It seems that there is no problem with the two ports.` you were stating it is working with `basicfwd`. If it only present in the application it would be probelm

Comment: Thank you again! Replacing `rte_eth_link_get_nowait` with `rte_eth_link_get` does help, now the program can work normally. Could you explain the reason in detail? I update the NIC settings in **2020/7/2 Update**

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer to close the question